# What happened with Charlotte Richards in Lucifer's finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

**SPOILERS: LUCIFER SEASON 2**

In Lucifer's season 2

> Lucifer's mother gets out of Hell and invests a newly dead human's body, Charlotte Richards.

Now in the finale episode

> Lucifer uses the flaming sword to open a new world for his mother to go to. She leaves Charlotte's body and Charlotte wakes up as if nothing happened even though she should be dead.

If they had just let her dead body take the shot and pretend like this is what she had died from it would have been a lot simpler to explain than why she doesn't remember Lucifer.

Was there any word or explanation from the director as to why this happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why...basically to keep Tricia Helfer around and use the character of Charlotte to tell new stories.

Producer Joe Henderson...in an interview with [BuddyTV](http://www.buddytv.com/articles/lucifer/lucifer-interview-where-is-lucifer-64885.aspx)

> **BTV:** Will we see her again?
>
> **JH:** The only thing I'll say is Charlotte Richards is breathing at the end [of the finale]. When it comes to Mom, we'll see. She's a great character and archetype. The question just becomes as we figure things out what story we have, right now, she's off in her own world and building her own things. I'm sure it's something we'll probably come back to at some point.
>
> **BTV:** What about Charlotte?
>
> **JH:** Tricia Helfer is an amazing actress and we adore her. It's not the last we'll see of her. She's in our cast for Season 3. She's awesome. We adore her. She brought so much energy and life to the character of Mom, as well as, to the show. We can't wait to see what varying different things we do with her in Season 3.
>
> **BTV:** It's interesting because Charlotte will have different effects on each character and having a lawyer available as she has been this season would be intriguing too.
>
> **JH:** That opportunity to explore both that side of the world as well as the moral quandaries that come from it. I feel that's where our show lives so much dealing with morality, dealing with right or wrong, and that's a side of the world which very much dips into it.

Comment: Kind of let down that it's just for that. Thank you for your answer